# Are questions specifically about movie theatres, and irrelevant of the actual movies they are playing, considered on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[A user just asked a question involving the volume of movie theatres](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76473/whats-with-the-loud-previews), when the previews come on. I immediately felt the question could do with a tag cleanup; it uses the tags [soundtrack](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack) and [previews](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/previews).

- [soundtrack](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack) seems irrelevant, even as a meta tag; the question specifically asks about the volume of previews, which has nothing to do with the musical score for the actual movie.
- [previews](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/previews) seems completely relevant - until I noticed that this tag was specifically created for this question.

This leads me to wonder if this sort of question is actually *on-topic*; but I can not find any supporting meta article. Are questions specifically about movie theatres, and irrelevant of the actual movies they are playing, considered on topic?

Note that I am more concerned about the context of *movie theatres*, not about the actual question, itself. The question may or may not have further issues; that is not something I mean to debate.

Comment: The `previews` tag is certainly irrelevant and, anyway, we already have a `trailers` tag. Nor is the `soundtrack` tag appropriate. Edited tags accordingly. And yes, it's off-topic IMO.

Comment: @Paulie_D, could you provide an argument as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In it's present state, I think the question is off-topic.

The situation might be individual to the single OP &/or theatre in question and, as such there is no objective measure that could be used to answer the question...again, *as it stands*.

That said, **there could be a good question in there**.

Something along the lines of:

> It seems to me that the sound volume in movie trailers is higher than the features themselves.
>
> Are there any specific regulations or guidelines regarding movie trailer sound levels?
>
> Is there any scientific evidence behind this observation and, if so, what is the reasoning behind having the sound that much louder?

---

On the subject of Movie Theatres themselves...then I'd say **NO** they aren't relevant to movies and tv shows themselves.

I suppose there could be an *edge case* where the physical surroundings (surround sound, etc?) are relevant to the question on a movies but those should be actioned on a case by case basis.

Comment: Yes. We do have a rule about "Technology questions about playing content" being off topic. We don't allow questions about TVs or DVD/BluRay players or Streaming services. I think this is covered there.

Answer (score -3):

We have many questions regarding movie theaters, which have no relation to a specific movie.

See the film-industry, cinema-history and distribution tags.

While some will down vote and VTC them regardless of quality or on-topic-ness, they are welcomed on here, as they fit the spirit of the site. I remember there is one highly voted question on popcorn and movie theaters that's a highly similar example as the one in question, but can't find it atm. Will add it in.

Comment: None of the mentioned tags seem to relate to what I am asking about; especially given the explicit usage description. I am also sceptical of a question about popcorn that does not come up when you search for "popcorn".